# The accuracy of Force Sensitive Resistors (FSRs)

Tags: resistors, touch-panel

I am trying to make a large scale resistive touch sensor with 4 FSRs, one for each corner of the rectangular sensor. The pressure that I'm going to be applying will  be a moderately pressured finger press. I have heard that FSRs are mostly inaccurate as far as precise pressure goes.

For example, the [Interlink 402](https://www.adafruit.com/product/166) says in its [datasheet](http://www.interlinkelectronics.com/datasheets/Datasheet_FSR.pdf) that its accuracy is within 2% of its resistive value, and changes with time at a rate of 5% * log<sub>10</sub>( days ).

As far as tap sensitivity goes, the FSR seems decent, at 10% change after 10 million taps.

I'm wondering if with a passive load of 2kg, and a dynamic load of 1kg, would the 4 FSRs be sensitive enough to make a decent (512x512 (9-bit accuracy)), reliable resistive touch screen, or are other materials better for the cost? If I were to make this, what would my theoretical accuracy be?

Comment: Link to the data sheet for the FSR would help.

Comment: @Andyaka boom. I was editing the question as you posted that comment.

Comment: I think the data sheet provides you all the information you need.

Comment: Notice that it has 10% hysteresis.  Real force touch screens as used on phones and trackpads use different force measuring techniques.

Comment: @KevinWhite I thought that these did make up resistive screens?

Comment: @tuskiomi - normal resistive touch screens do not measure force and use a completely different arrangement. Very few touch screens measure force.

Comment: 1kg load sounds like a hammer more than a finger. Note the sensitivity is given for one batch only and tolerance between batches must be compensated or calibrated and a matched lead-lag filter is my suggestion to compensate for these tolerances made to conjugate the fundamental spectrum of the dynamic load. ( fo=Hz toggle rate) ie. gain above DC null > fo = 10dB

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 2.2 pounds is less than what would be registered if I rested  on arm on top of it. When I was 13 I squeezed a scale to get 40 kg, or 20 for each hand. not sure if that's strong or not, but i only need 1/20 of that for a solid contact.

Comment: ok 1kg arm but  a 1kg dynamic force, is a heavy touch and must be gender exclusive. ;)  What kind of tool is this? for high volume? or 1 of kind?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 this is going to be a smart board reduxed to a coffee table for D&D

Comment: @tuskiomi Cool. Want one. Make it happen. ;)

Comment: It looks more like table banging sensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa9Lq0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

300mV deflection at 2/3 FSR rating for load from 2/3 to 1 x FSR rating ?

[image]

Static load is probably quasi static, so dynamic touch will be problematic so DC tracking by AC amplification

Some problems with OEM specs at 10k expecting 2.5V at 50% FSR but only seeing 20% on left.

- batch to batch variations may need a pot anyways.

### Conclusion

- possible if static load is true static.
- undefined problems with this approach.

Comment: Interesting.  There is likely a better way then, huh?

Comment: First specify all user interface dynamics in 4D, XYZ,t including resolution delta {XYZ,t}

Comment: Nono, i can't expect you to do any more for me; you've done much more than enough.  nor anyone else.  I'll go on to do as much as i can until i hit a block

Comment: start with good interface specs not design.